# Como uso o @media para bloquear padding-top em resoluções menores?

Tags: css

Como eu faço  bloquear o 'padding'  dessa função

```
   <div style=" width: 300px;  float:left; padding-top:68px" > no @media ?
```

O objetivo e bloquear o 'padding' em resoluções menores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `class` junto com `@media`:

```css
.minha-div {
  padding-top: 68px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .minha-div {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="" class="minha-div">

</div>
```

Nesse [link](http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/) tem um tutorial de como utilizar as medias queries do CSS.

Comment: funcionou Vlw cara

Comment: Quando a resposta solucionar o problema, marque-a como correta. xD

Comment: Foi mal pela nubagem, marcado.

Answer (score 1):

No CSS as regras são aplicadas na ordem... no seu caso provavelmente carrega antes do html.

Tente colocar !important na sua regra dentro @media

```
@media... {
   .classeDaDiv {
       padding-top: 0 !important;
```

Comment: Vlw por responder